# Unitary and Involutory Matrices

Tags: matrices

Does it follow from the unitarity and involution of the matrix that it is Hermitian? I think of the identity matrix as a concrete example. I wonder if this true in general? I'm not a mathematician. I'm just curious.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does.

If $U$ is unitary, then $U^{-1} = U^*$ (where I am using $U^*$ to denote the conjugate-transpose of $U$). If $U$ is an involution, then $U^{-1} = U$. It follows that if $U$ is unitary and an involution, then $U$ and $U^*$ are both equal to $U^{-1}$ so that $U = U^*$, which is to say that $U$ is Hermitian.

Comment: So, the set of Hermitian matrices is a subset of the set of unitary matrices.

Comment: @TomášKubalík No. For example, if $I$ is the identity matrix, then $2I$ is Hermitian but not unitary. The unitary matrices and the Hermitian matrices are two sets that have an overlap. The unitary matrices that are Hermitian are precisely those that are involutions. The Hermitian matrices that are unitary are precisely those that have only $\pm 1$ as their only eigenvalues.